# RC Circuit with dependent source

Tags: capacitor

How to find i(t) t>0.I stuck.If cannot help me okey.[image][image][image]

Comment: Please, post a better picture. Many people here, me included, won't bother helping people not showing the minimal effort to ease our task. Your picture makes my eyes hurt.

Answer (score 0):

No full solutions to homeworks, only guidance!

Only the capacitor in your circuit needs something based on differential equations. Even it can be handled elementarily because the charging of the capacitor obeys a well known equation:

\$U_c = U_t + (U_{co}-U_t)e^{\frac{-t}{RC}}\$ where

- Uc=capacitor voltage
- Uco=initial value of Uc
- Ut=Thevenin equivalent voltage seen by the capacitor
- R=Thevenin equivalent resistance seen by the capacitor
- t=time
- C=capacitance

So, you must calculate

- the initial voltage of the capacitor when the switch still was closed; assume a steady state, the cap is fully charged to the voltage what the rest of the circuit can offer, Uco=Uc when the current of the capacitor is zero, solve the KVL equation for Uc.
- the Thevenin equivalent for the rest of the circuit seen by the capacitor when t>0 and the switch is open
- the final numeric equation for Uc
- the equation how the asked current i depends on Uc
- the final numeric equation for i by substituting the equation of Uc.

As well you can form the equation for current i in Laplace domain and find the solution with Laplace transforms. This sounds simpler but the amount of work is quite the same.

**An auxiliary hint**: There's total 80 ohm resistance with current i. The controlled source in parallel gives exactly half of it. Together the controlled source and the 50+30 ohm resistance are equivalent with a 160 ohm resistance when seen by the rest of the circuit.

An opinion: This would be an excellent question in an exam. Persons who have things clear in their heads need few minutes for full solution, the others can fight a hour with no result.